# Parsing a date in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, date, coldfusion

I have a date stored in the format dd-mm-yyyy. I want to store the day, date and year as individual variables, while getting rid of any leading zeros (e.g. "09-09-2010" is stored as 9, 9, 2010).

I attempted to use the code on [this page](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2058-RESplit-Splitting-Strings-With-Regular-Expressions-In-ColdFusion.htm) to split the date by dashes, but it is throwing expression errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Some people, when confronted with a
>   problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have
>   two problems.

[Coding Horror: Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Investigate the ColdFusion functions [month](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_05.html)(date), [day](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_c-d_31.html#1103422)(date) and [year](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_t-z_27.html#140406)(date).

**Update**: you can pass a string to these functions so long as CF can turn into a date.

Answer (score 2):

When you say that you have a date

> stored in the format dd-mm-yyyy

are you sure you aren't confusing this with the way that your database UI is presenting it to you or are you actually storing the date in this format (for example, by writing it this way to a text file or a varchar column rather than a DateTime column)?

The reason I ask is that if a date is stored in a database as a date then CF will represent it as a date irrespective of how it appears in, say, SQL Management Studio. If this is the case then you can simply split the parts out using DatePart("datepart", "date"). 
If you have a date in a text format (such as from a form submission or because it has been stored as plain text) then you should be able to parse it in to a DateTime object using LSParseDateTime() and then use the DatePart(...) method on it to split out the parts.

See http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_30.html

(sorry, can't post the URL to the other function due to lack of SO points!)

for the documentation on this.

As an aside, if you are using SQL2005 (or later) then you can create computed columns on the date field in order to split out the day, year and month at the database level. I thought I'd mention this just in case it proves useful.

Steve

Comment: +1 fair enough, datepart() was the other possibility I'd considered. I'm guessing the questioner's issue is an unfamiliarity with CF and that it has a significant number of built-in date manipulation functions - hence the regex approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a string in that format, there's no need for regular expressions.

```
myDate = "13-12-2010";
theDay = listGetAt(myDate,1,"-");
theMonth = listGetAt(myDate,2,"-");
theYear = listGetAt(myDate,3,"-");
```

Using the `val()` function will also drop leading zeroes, if any.